# How to fix WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, machine-check-exception

I have problems with a blue screen while installing new software.
I'm getting the blue screen at the same installation step over and over again.
The software i'm trying to install is Android Studio.
It worked perfectly on the system before.

1. I'm running a freshly installed windows 10 with the latest drivers from the manufacturers website.
2. The hardware is selected from the manufacturers hardware compatibility list.

I reinstalled all drivers multiple times. The event log shows no other critical events except the already named blue screen error.
I don't know how to fix this issue, it starts getting annoying.

Here are 2 dump files from my installation attempts

1. http://www.file-upload.net/download-11409263/032016-14937-01.dmp.html
2. http://www.file-upload.net/download-11409264/032016-18234-01.dmp.html

I hope someone is able to read the dump file properly and help me track down the issue.

Comment: 124 is a hardware error. Test your memory.

Answer (score 2):

You have an issue with the L2 Cache (DCACHEL2_DRD_ERR) of your CPU, which reading data from it:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: ffffe001322cc028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000be000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000001001136, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for rt640x64.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for rt640x64.sys

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.162.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160223-1728

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  MSI

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  MS-7922

SYSTEM_SKU:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  2.0

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  V10.3

BIOS_DATE:  01/05/2015

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  MSI

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:   Z97S SLI Krait Edition (MS-7922)

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  2.0

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3c,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 1E'00000000 (cache) 1E'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  f


STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 hal!HalBugCheckSystem
02 nt!WheaReportHwError
03 hal!HalpMcaReportError
04 hal!HalpMceHandlerCore
05 hal!HalpMceHandler
06 hal!HalpMceHandlerWithRendezvous
07 hal!HalHandleMcheck
08 nt!KxMcheckAbort
09 nt!KiMcheckAbort
0a rt640x64


BUCKET_ID:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_CACHE

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x124_genuineintel_processor_cache



1: kd> !errrec ffffe001322cc028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffffe001322cc028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d182cc3cd9ef88
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 3/20/2016 17:24:02 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe001322cc0a8
Section       @ ffffe001322cc180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Data Read
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 2
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000306c3
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000002

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe001322cc0f0
Section       @ ffffe001322cc240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000002
CPU Id        : c3 06 03 00 00 08 10 02 - bf fb fa 7f ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffffe001322cc240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe001322cc138
Section       @ ffffe001322cc2c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : DCACHEL2_DRD_ERR (Proc 1 Bank 5)
  Status      : 0xbe00000001001136
  Address     : 0x00000000f80e3100
  Misc.       : 0x0000007042000086
```

Sometime a BIOS/UEFI update can fix it. So look for a newer BIOS/UEFI version and flash it.

Comment: I updated the BIOS and also updated all drivers again. I was able to track down the issue to the installation of Intel HAXM which comes with Android Studio. Android Studio is running perfectly well but i'm still not able to install Intel HAXM. Its the same bluescreen.

Comment: ok, contact Intel support about the HAXM issue

Answer (score 1):

It's a [machine check exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception), which usually means a faulty CPU. In your case, however, it looks like there's an issue with Avast! virtualizing applications for sandboxing purposes. See this [Intel forum post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/android-applications-on-intel-architecture/topic/562627):

> If you are using Avast go to Settings -> Troubleshooting and [Disable] 'Enable hardware -assisted virtualization.
>
> HAXM will install if you have no other issues....

Note that this might reduce your system's security, so be sure you understand the effects of this change.

If you have any other application that uses hardware-assisted virtualization (VT-x), you may need to stop using it to run HAXM.

Answer (score -1):

These are called BCC124 and are related to hardware.  Read how to diagnose and hopefully to fix them in this wiki

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-update/bugcheck-code-124/98c998d2-447a-40ce-ae1f-8211e355f14d